# Получить уникальные значения в рядах датафрейма

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть данные [data](https://dropmefiles.com/csfUb) - это 12 столбцов с комбинациями по 12 значений в каждом. Как можно сократить значения в строках, чтобы убрать в каждой строке одинаковые значения и записать это в новый датафрейм с двумя столбцами (index и второй любой)?

К примеру, было ---> стало:

```
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   --->   1 2
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2   12   8   8   --->   1 2 12 8
1   1   1   11   11   1   7   4   7   7   2   9   --->   1 11 7 4 2 9
```

Результат:

```
     column
1    1 1
2    1 2 
3    1 3
4    1 4
...
1891 8 7 9 1
1892 8 7 9 2
1893 8 7 9 3
...
```

Данные data которые сейчас:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('12.csv')
data
```

```
        1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12

0       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
2       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3
3       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   4
4       1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   5
...
1352073 11  11  11  11  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
1352074 11  11  11  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
1352075 11  11  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
1352076 11  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
1352077 12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
```

Comment: В каком виде должен быть результат? В воде строки или списка?

Comment: Датафрейм - это понятно. Какой тип данных вы ждёте в колонке column в результате?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Допустим, есть датафрейм:

```
df:
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
2   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   3
3   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   4
4   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   5
5  10  11  11  11  12  12  12  12  12  12  12  12
```

тогда:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: x.unique().tolist(), axis=1)
```

res, соответственно, будет:

```
0             [1]
1          [1, 2]
2          [1, 3]
3          [1, 4]
4          [1, 5]
5    [10, 11, 12]
```

где в колонке все уникальные числа начального датафрейма будут представлены в виде списков

Можно сделать так:

```
res = df.apply(lambda x: " ".join(x.unique().astype("str").tolist()), axis=1)
```

тогда res будет:

```
0           1
1         1 2
2         1 3
3         1 4
4         1 5
5    10 11 12
```

где в колонке уникальные числа исходного датафрейма будут представлены в виде строки с пробелами.